# Find specific property then push to an array

Tags: javascript

I have to the following json file. My goal is to find all `name` properly and add its value to name array.

```
var data = {
  "Fruits": [{
    "name": "apple",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "orange",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "strawberry",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "banana",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }],
  "Meat": [{
    "name": "beef",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "chicken",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "fish",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "pork",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }],
  "Vegetable": [{
    "name": "cucumber",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "kale",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }],
  "Spice": [{
    "name": "cajun",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "garlic",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }]
};
```

I came up with something like this, but give me error on `push` function. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

```
var name = [];
for (var key in data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
    console.log(data[key][i].name);
    name.push(data[key][i].name);
  }
}
console.log(name);
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the variable name `name`, since it is in the global scope you are trying to override the `window.name` property which takes only string values

```js
var data = {
  "Fruits": [{
    "name": "apple",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "orange",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "strawberry",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "banana",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }],
  "Meat": [{
    "name": "beef",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "chicken",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "fish",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "pork",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }],
  "Vegetable": [{
    "name": "cucumber",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "kale",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }],
  "Spice": [{
    "name": "cajun",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }, {
    "name": "garlic",
    "added_date": "",
    "expired_date": ""
  }]
};

var name = [];
snippet.log('name value:' + name + ':' + typeof name + ':')

var names = [];
for (var key in data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
    names.push(data[key][i].name);
  }
}
snippet.log(names);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is correct, of course, but the real question is why the OP has written code which runs in the global context, where `name` is already defined with a special meaning, instead of just writing this in a function, which would work fine.